# I experience 'access is denied' error in hugo

Tags: windows-10, hugo

I execute the following command using Windows 10 PowerShell:
`./hugo -D`

Then I get the following error:

```
Error copying static files: open C:\Users\user\desktop\examplesite\public\images\gohugo-default-sample-hero-image.jpg: Access is denied.
```

It looks like my folder with website static content has specific attributes which block Hugo from writing/copying files. I granted full access in security tab of this folder to both Administrator and System, but still the same error appears.

Comment: Try the suggestions here: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/windows-permissions-error-copying-static-files/30676/4

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you. I tried all the suggestions there, but unfortunately they haven't worked out both for me and the user who asked the same question there.

Comment: I wasn't sure there was any viable workaround in the thread, but I thought I'd pass it on.  I found other, similar threads from 2014: https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/636, https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/688.  It looks like Go/Hugo is making assumptions about "file attributes" (modification date, access permissions, etc.) that simply don't apply to Windows.  And it sounds like the reply is "That's a Microsoft problem." SUGGESTION: Consider WSL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10